# Request to update only part of the page Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, request

I am new to Spring MVC. 
When the page is loading for the first time, it executing the request and returns ModelAndView object. The same request (but with params user selected will be executed when Button1 clicked);

I want to be able by clicking on another button (let's say Button2), execute another request that will return only Model that contains list of objects and update only PART of the page, while the data from the main request will be still on the page (except for the updated part).

I'm not understanding how can I accomplish this. For my situation it's impossible to do both requests as one and update whole page when second button is clicked. I cannot do both requests in the same controller methods, because first request(Button1) is quite expensive for us because of huge amount of data it's loading.

Comment: You need javascript to have dynamic web pages. In general I would consider ditching the template methodology of Spring MVC for pages, and consider developing an API instead.

Comment: @Snickers3192 is template the same as tags ?

Comment: @Snickers3192 can I use ajax request to update part of the page?

Comment: Yes to get dynamic pages you need javascript.

Comment: Templating with thymeleaf or whatever templating library IMO is a bad idea. Better to make a react app and create a microservice which your react app/angular uses, is the modern methodology now.